# Why do I get error for using the brackets for vector n=[0:50]; when it is correct

Tags: matlab, syntax, syntax-error

I get use of brackets is unnecessary []. Use parenthood if needed.

```
 subplot(211);
 x=impseq(0,0,50);
 n=[0:50];
 h=filter(Ns,Ds,x);
 stem(n,x);
 grid;
 xlabel('Otcheti vav vremeto');
 title('Delta impuls');
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of brackets in this case is unnecessary. This is because brackets are used to perform implicit concatenation of values:

```
a = [1,2,3];
```

You can also use them to concatenate two arrays:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
```

In your case, the colon operator (`:`) already creates an array and you don't need to concatenate anything. Your code is essentially the same as

```
[[0,1,2,3,4,...50]]
```

As you can see, the parentheses are redundant.

This should only yield a *syntax warning* and should not cause an *execution error* in your program.